# How can I use Unity toggles and toggle groups to save a selected toggle in a toggle group as player prefs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, togglebutton

I have a scene with input fields and toggle groups I want to save the player input in playerprefs as I will be reusing it in consecutive game sessions. I would also like to get the text from the label of the toggle selected in the toggle group. Here is my code so far. I have a compiler error that says I cannot convert guitext to a string. I think I have the inputfield strings saved just fine its the toggle groups that are tricky.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class CreateHolder : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField Input1;
    public InputField Input2;
    public InputField Input3;
    public InputField Input4;
    public ToggleGroup Discount;
    public ToggleGroup Params;
    public ToggleGroup Time;


    public void Grabdata() {

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offername", Input1.text);
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Offername") == true) 
    {
            Debug.Log("something has saved");
            Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Input1").ToString());
    }

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offerdesc", Input2.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offeramount", Input3.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offerpercent", Input4.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Tog1", Discount.GetComponent<GUIText>());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Tog2", Params.GetComponent<GUIText>());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Tog3", Time.GetComponent<GUIText>());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class CreateHolder : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField Input1;
    public InputField Input2;
    public InputField Input3;
    public InputField Input4;
    public ToggleGroup Discount;
    public ToggleGroup Params;
    public ToggleGroup Time;


    public void Grabdata() {

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offername", Input1.text);
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Offername") == true) 
    {
            Debug.Log("something has saved");
            Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Input1"));
    }

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offerdesc", Input2.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offeramount", Input3.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offerpercent", Input4.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Tog1", Discount.GetComponent<GUIText>().text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Tog2", Params.GetComponent<GUIText>().text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Tog3", Time.GetComponent<GUIText>().text);
    }
    }
```